# Jupyterhub cannot start server - 500 error

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I am trying to run jupyter hub for multiuser mode. I installed jupyterhub from PIP.

> [root@ip-of-machine hadoop]# echo $PATH
>
> /usr/local/bin/jupyterhub-singleuser:/usr/local/bin/jupyterhub:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin

When I tun jupyterhub I get an error saying

> 500 : Internal Server Error
>
> Failed to start your server. Please contact admin.

I ran it as

```
[root@ip-of-machine hadoop]# /usr/local/bin/jupyterhub -f ./jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py --no-ssl
```

The logs contain

```
[I 2016-05-03 17:13:09.406 JupyterHub spawner:465] Spawning jupyterhub-singleuser --user=jupyter --port=40770 --cookie-name=jupyter-hub-token-jupyter --base-url=/user/jupyter --hub-host= --hub-prefix=/hub/ --hub-api-url=http://127.0.0.1:8081/hub/api --ip=127.0.0.1
[E 2016-05-03 17:13:09.433 JupyterHub user:237] Unhandled error starting jupyter's server: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'jupyterhub-singleuser'
```

But there is singleuser in path. I explicitly added it to path and exported.

Any clues? Thanks.

Comment: I do have the same problem, my path is right though. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

PATH should contain a list of *directories* containing executables that should be found, not the executables themselves.

So instead of

```
/usr/local/bin/jupyterhub-singleuser:/usr/local/bin/jupyterhub:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin
```

your PATH should be:

```
/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin
```

which should find both `jupyterhub` and `jupyterhub-singleuser`.