# jupyterhub: command not found

Tags: jupyter, jupyterhub

I am trying to run the jupyterhub locally on Ubuntu 16.04; however, I cannot seem to run the jupyterhub command on the terminal, and I get the command not found error. I have installed jupyterhub by running the following commands:

```
sudo npm install -g configurable-http-proxy
pip3 install jupyterhub    
pip3 install --upgrade notebook
```

All of the above packages install successfully. My `PATH` variable in `/etc/environment` has been set as follows:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/root/bin"
```

Comment: I also tried to change my `PATH` variable as mentioned here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010454/jupyterhub-cannot-start-server-500-error) but still no success.

Comment: I also registered the kernels for both Python 2 and 3 by running the following commands: `python3 -m pip install jupyterhub notebook ipykernel`, `python3 -m ipykernel install`, `python2 -m pip install ipykernel`
`python2 -m ipykernel install`

Answer (score 1):

You need to start a Jupyter service, if you create environments with anaconda you can use them later inside the jupyter as kernels, so you can have a variety of library environments as you like.

There are also other functions to give resource guarantee or limits, or initial folders for your hub.

You can edit all this in your jupyterhub_config.py file.

I leave you here my github with a complete guide for the configuration and installation.

[Github/Jupyter](https://github.com/Nouvellie/ubuntu/blob/ubuntu/contents/jupyter.md)

Comment: While we appreciate you taking the time to answer the question, you should clarify inside the answer that you are directly affiliated with the link that you posted. As it stands now, your answer can be considered borderline self-promotion

Comment: I understand, I've fixed my answer.

Answer (score -2):

If you can first install Anaconda.

Then install the configurable proxy.

Run commands -

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterhub  # installs jupyterhub and proxy
conda install notebook  # needed if running the notebook servers locally
```

Now try jupyterhub